# Dependency Inversion. Не понимаю как оно должно работать

Tags: c#, solid

Всем доброго времени суток. Итак, вот уже где-то месяца 4 я пытаюсь познать SOLID. Большая проблема в понимании Dependency Inversion. Все остальные на мой взгляд намного легче. И конечно, чем больше пытаешься вникнуть, чем больше читаешь про принцип, тем больше каша в голове. Итак, вот она - самая популярная картинка принципа в действии. 
[image: Это самая распространенная картинка]

Итак, допустим, я представляю себе, например, основной слой бизнес-логики, в нем мы определяем интерфейс сервиса какого-то (IService). Дальше, в более нижнем слое мы реализуем его (ImplementedService). Я пишу на c# и я понимаю все вышесказанное так - у меня в solution есть проект с бизнес логикой, и есть проект с сервисами. И в последнем у меня есть reference на проект верхнего уровня (иначе как он узнает о существовании даже интерфейса, да и вроде как в этом смысл DIP). Итак, окей, тут мой мозг готов (не без боли) это уложить и понять.

Идем дальше. А дальше, у меня в сервисе, например, нужна работа со строками, простая такая (конкатенация, тримы, реплэйсы). И я думаю, хммм, это же уже какая-то утилита должна быть. Итак, значит, следуя DIP, я определяю нужный себе интерфейс в слое с реализацией сервиса (IStringUtility). И дальше, на еще более низшем слое я его реализую. Итак, как и на предыдущем этапе, у меня в solution появляется третий проект для всякой всячины, в котором лежит ImplementationStringUtility и который имеет reference на слой с сервисами. Но вот в отличие от прошлого раза, тут мой мозг отказывается это понимать. Ну как? Как? У меня есть простой классик, который работает со строками, почему он, следуя принципу, должен еще в себя впихивать кучу reference, которые ему не нужны? Да и с сервисами примерно то же самое. Если у меня есть низкий уровень общения с БД, то как-то логичней как раз таки его делать отделенным от бизнес-логики, а не впихивать в проект reference на нее? На мой глупый неопытный взгляд все выглядит как какая-то несуразица, но не могут же все ошибаться, а мое мнение правильное.

Вопрос: так как все таки в с# организовать правильный DIP?

Comment: Не усложняйте. DI состоит в том, чтобы вместо явного создания ресурса получить его извне с возможностью подменять. Поэтому все, что может быть заменено или должно (для тестов например) нужно передавать извне. StringUtility передавать нет смысла, если у вас их не 2 варианта.

Comment: @vitidev Стойте, Вы ведь про Dependency Injection написали? Это другое.

Comment: А нужно ли делать зависимость именно на абстракцию StringUtility? У вас будет несколько имплементаций этого интерфейса?

Comment: От себя рекомендую книгу [Dependency Injection in .NET](http://www.amazon.com/Dependency-Injection-NET-Mark-Seemann/dp/1935182501). Она хоть и про DI, но и про DIP вы там тоже найдете много полезного. В терминах этой книги классы типа StringUtility называются *стабильной* зависимостью, поэтому делать завязку на абстракцию не обязательно.

Comment: @kmv да, возможно тут это сверхсолид получается, но это только локальный пример.

Comment: @kmv а что насчет слоя БД? понятно, что всякие хелперы - это мелочи, которые уже можно оставить как есть, но насчет БД - этот пример мне вообще неясен.

Comment: @user2216 здесь стандартное решение - паттерны Repository, Unit of Work. В либу с интерфейсами помещается интерфейс репозитория, в библиотеке слоя БД он имплементится, слой бизнес-логики использует только интерфейс репозитория, принимая, скажем, аргументом конструктора объект с типом этого интерфейса. В центральном проекте создается конкретный экземпляр репозитория, он передается в конструктор сервиса бизнес-логики и т.д.

Comment: @kmv все просто круто! спасибо! в голове вроде все сложилось после вашего комментария. Надеюсь, что надолго. Действительно, я привязалась сильно к примеру в книге Дяди Боба и словам "верхний уровень определяет интерфейс", а по факту же "верхний уровень не должен зависеть от нижнего", что совсем наоборот. Пример с репозиторием подходит под это определение и многое ставит на свои места.

Comment: @kmv может быть оформите ответ?